# How to setup for live player / observer pair w/ voice chat in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding, streaming

I'm trying to build a setup for educational use of Minecraft:

**One person plays Minecraft, another person watches live online *with the least lag/latency possible,* and the pair can talk over high-quality voice chat.**

What is the best setup to allow this?

**Scenario A:**

1) Write a mod that allows a watcher to be a passive spectator through their copy of Minecraft? The watcher would see exactly what the player sees.  Would this be the fastest and clearest picture? Is it a trivial mod to write?

2) Connect together over Hamachi? Can that be dead-easy to set up?

3) Use a voice-chat in the game itself?

**Scenario B:**

1) Use a streaming video technology. (Twitch? Google Hangouts? Something else?)

2) Third party voice chat like Skype. (Or just Google Hangouts?)

My fear here is lag, low quality video, bandwidth.

**Scenario C ?**

---

*Thanks very much for any help :)*

Comment: This is a rather broad question. It sounds like you should try writing such a mod and ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: @Anko Thanks, I guess that's a fair point. I've never yet written a mod, but there's no time like the present...